# Prevent Blazor WebAssembly submiting form on pressing enter

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just spent ages trying to get Blazor not to submit and reload the page but fire off my methods instead on enter key. With

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-text" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeydown="Enter" @bind-value="@searchString" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Whenever I hit enter the page would get reloaded if I used the enter key instead of click, preventing the results from showing. So I added

```
<button type="submit" disabled hidden></button>
```

Which fixed it.

Now this to me looks like a workaround. Is there a more elegant way to do this? If I had the original button as submit it wouldnt work either. I think this works because there is a submit button for the enter key to hit, but being disabled it cant do anything.

Comment: The problem is the `<form>` tag you left out here. The solution begins with actually removing the `<form>` tag.

Comment: [Polite] What's wrong with using the Blazor Editform?  It's the Blazor implementation of `Form`.  See MSDocs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0. on the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `form` tag is wrong in most cases under Blazor, anyway you can find a good example of using conditionally keydown here:
https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/forms-and-validation/how-do-i-conditionally-preventdefault-inside-the-input-component-in-blazor